# localhost stops working after refresh

Tags: apache, localhost

I have a weird issue with localhost on my Mac. I'm trying to setup Apache server, but I'm just stuck with the localhost. So on a new tab if I type in localhost and press enter, it shows 'It works'. But if I then refresh the page, it only disconnects and says 'The site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect.'
I've followed all the steps in several tutorials about setting this up but nothing solves this issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I could make it work. I noticed that there was this line `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` at the end of the httpd.conf file which was overwriting any of my other conf files, so it wasn't letting localhost work normally.

I first uncommented it and localhost worked, I could also see my directories in the browser. But then another issue came up, that the phpinfo.php page wasn't showing up the usual phpinfo, instead it was showing me the code in the file for rendering phpinfo.

After googling around I learnt that because I had upgraded my PHP earlier to version 7.1, this new installation uses a conf file inside the 'other' directory ([read this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/)) to make php work and also comments out the php5_module line in httpd.conf to disable older php. I had instead uncommented this line and commented out the line to include this other conf file. So in order to deal with both the first case and this one, I simply commented out php5_module line again and then moved this line for including other conf file to a place above where I was including my conf file. And everything worked :)